# 喪中 dialogue in incense commercial

Tags: translation

I have trouble understanding [this commercial](http://cm-watch.net/nipponkodo-mochu/).

(This page also provides Japanese subtitles)

The woman has received a lot of 喪中はがき lately and so is worried about お香典.
This part I understand but what the old guy says next is puzzling to me:

> 「私ね進物用のお線香を贈ってるんです。喪中見舞いって書いて お返しなんかいいから今度ゆっくり話し聞かせてって気持ちでね」と笹野さん

I get it that he recommends giving お線香, possibly because it's easier on the purse, but what he says later is hard to parse:

> "お返しなんかいいから今度ゆっくり話し聞かせてって気持ちでね"

My best try: he says the meaning of お線香 is "not to ask something in return" (お返しなんかいいから) but to "pay respect and have a leisurely chat". Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The commercial makes perfect sense.  It does not to you because you are trying to understand linguistically what is essentially an inexplicit cultural question.  I do not think you fully understand what お返し means here.  Additionally, "easier on the purse" is neither said nor implied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are concerning about the custom of 香典 and [香典返し](https://www.ringbell.co.jp/giftconcierge/2898). 香典 is a monetary gift given usually on the day of the funeral, and 香典返し is a small returning gift given usually several weeks after the funeral. She is worrying if it's too late to formally offer a 香典 because it may make the bereaved family worry about 香典返し.

> お返しなんかいいから今度ゆっくり話し聞かせてって気持ちでね
>   (I present *senko*) thinking "No returning gift is necessary, but please let me know about the deceased person sometime soon".

This ad makes sense partly because *senko* is not expensive and partly because giving *senko* is (as far as I know) not a popular custom.

Answer (score 0):

In case you receive お線香 as a gift for mourning, you don't have to send something back to the giver. He's making a deal to pretend as if he wants a chat with the receiver, but he's trying to comfort the receiver more.
It's a cool technique.